# Cannot get Dynamics CRM 2013 working with Visual Studio 2015 RC on Win 10? [.NETCore / .NETFramework]

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I've recently upgraded to `Windows 10` and installed `Visual Studio Professional 2015 RC` and I'm trying to use `Dynamics CRM 2013` in my **Universal Windows project**, but I seem to be unable to add the references.

The error I am receiving is -

> A reference to 'location of .dll' could not be added.    The project
>   targets '.NETCore' while the file reference   targets '.NETFramework'.
>   This is not a supported scenario.

Now, In previous versions I understand that we were able to go to `Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Application` and select target framework from there, which would have been a good place to start in trying to fix this, but `Visual Studio 2015 RC` does not seem to have this feature.

What can I do to fix this, or is this something that is just entirely incompatible at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are targeting the wrong version of the .NET Framework.  The CRM 2013 SDK Assemblies support the .NET 4.0 Framework (2015 supports 4.5).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350(v=crm.6).aspx

You can change the framework that visual studio is targeting to the .NET 4.0 Framework.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.140).aspx

This should allow you reference the CRM Assemblies.

EDIT:
If you are building a windows store app you can't change the target framework.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this publication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx), *"Visual Studio 2015 RTM cannot be used to build Windows Universal Apps until 7/29/2015".*

Comment: I agree that the answer should include the essential part of the answer, which in the case of my initial answer was italicized.